# TypeScript Build Error : Property does not exist on type 'IStateParamsService'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, definitelytyped

I am using TypeScript almost entire of my client project. Currently I am facing a technical problem.

In my HTML, I have an anchor tag like below :

```
    <a class="btn btn-default mrm" ui-sref="course-detail({courseId: '{{c.Id}}'})">Details</a>
```

In my course detail controller, I am getting the values in the stateparam variable. But if I want to access my 'courseId' from that variable, it is giving me build error. Please check the image below.

[image: TypeScript Code with Build Error]

But if I remove the IF block, then I am getting the log in the developer console like below.

[image: Console Log by commenting the build error code]

I must get the course Id property and value to proceed. Otherwise I need to code this controller in pure angularjs which I don't want. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typescript prefers to work on maps explicitly through brackets notation [].

If you want to get a field out of a map-like object you should use square brackets instead of dot notation:

```
if (this.param['courseId'] === "00000....0000") {
  //.. rest of the code
```

That should solve the immediate issue you're facing.

Comment: Why? I hate brackets notation, it's ugly to me.
Can I disable that?