# Angular 2 - Error "Property 'iconName' does not exist on type 'StateParams'

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, webpack, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I am using ui-router-ng2 to handle my routing in my web app. I am currently sending an string(iconName) as parameters from one view to another.

Here is my code for icon.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { StateService } from 'ui-router-ng2';

@Component({
  selector: 'icon',
  templateUrl: 'icon.html',
})
export class IconComponent {
    StateService: StateService;
    iconName: StateService;


    constructor(stateService: StateService) {
        this.StateService = stateService;

        this.iconName = this.StateService.params.iconName;
    }
}
```

This is the line:
`this.iconName = this.StateService.params.iconName;` that is throwing the following error: `Property 'iconName' does not exist on type 'StateParams'.`

It may be that I need to initialize icoName and assign it to params? I'm just not sure how I should go about resolving this error

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I was using `params` incorrectly. This is how the line should of looked like:

`this.iconName = this.StateService.params['iconName'];`

Used this as a reference
[TypeScript Build Error : Property does not exist on type 'IStateParamsService'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528591/typescript-build-error-property-does-not-exist-on-type-istateparamsservice)